# How to change the color of a button when clicked, and when other button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hyperlink

I have an html site with sections. On the top of the site, I have buttons with link to every section *Default color: white*. I want, when I click on a button to change it's color, but also, when I click on ANOTHER button, to change the color of the other button, and make the old button color white again.

I tried some script examples from stackoverflow, but I never find something working like what I wanted.

Comment: Can you show us the related code that you have tried?

Comment: Here an article with the explanation of what you need, states: https://zellwk.com/blog/style-hover-focus-active-states/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a code like this :

```
function changeFirstButtonColor() {
 document.getElementById("first-btn").style.backgroundcolor = 'new color';
 document.getElementById("second-btn").style.backgroundcolor = 'old color';
}

function changeSecondButtonColor() {
 document.getElementById("second-btn").style.backgroundcolor = 'new color';
 document.getElementById("first-btn").style.backgroundcolor = 'old color';
}
```

And call the function for the good button with onclick event

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I just want to ask, because I am not familiar with JavaScript, how can I call each command for the current button?

Comment: Never mind. I looked for a tutorial and found the onclick method. Thanks for the help!